# What are the range and mode of the set {5}?

Tags: statistics

> What is the range of the set {5}? Is it zero? What about its mode? Is it 5?

This is taken from a GRE question. My reasoning is as follows:

1) The range is the highest value minus the lowest value, and since there is only one value, it should be zero.

2) The mode is the most frequent value, and hence is equal to the only value there is, namely 5.

I'm just not sure of this, and would like to make sure I'm not falling into an "exceptions" case.
$\,$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer and reasoning are correct here.  The range is $0$ and the mode is $5$.